# Should I ever reduce / cash out money from my stack when playing NL Holden cash games?

Tags: bankroll-management

I am trying to learn bankroll management. Is there any situation that I should cash out my profits and reduce my chip stack? Is that allowed by the rules?

Let's say I am playing $1/2 NL Holden with a maximum buy-in of $200 which gives you a bankroll of $4000. Let's say I have bought in 12 times already ($2400) and I finally hit a couple of big hands making my current stack $1000. Should I withdraw X from the $1000 and put it back to my pocket? Or keep playing with the $1000?

Answer (score 2):

This is called ratholing and is generally not allowed. If you want to remove money from the table you will probably at minimum be forced to sit out for some amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can not take out money from the table. The only thing you could do is get out of the table and come back later.

If 1000$ is a big portion of your bankroll you should consider stand up.

If you feel like you have good reads on your oponents and it is really easy to get their chips you could maybe consider staying. (In a way if you think it's that easy you can just to be safe get up and come back later and grind all the way up again.)

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, you must leave the table possibly being allowed to sit out and come back to your seat if your lucky.    You even have to leave the table in online poker if you want to bank any of your winnings.   The reason being is that the people who you won money from expect at least the chance to win it back while you are still at the table.

I use the bankroll management strategies that Jesus Ferguson used when he did the $0 to $10,000 challenge on full tilt, turning $0 into $10,000 in about a year and a half  (the first 7 months going from 0 to $6.50 playing freerolls)

**On leaving the table...**

> If at any time during a No-Limit or Pot-Limit cash-game session the
>   money on the table represented more than 10 percent of his total
>   bankroll, he had to leave the game when the blinds reached him

**Bankroll strategies for buy-ins ...**

- Cash game or STT/SNG -  Buy in must be 5 percent or less of total bankroll, or at lower limits, not more than $2.50.
- MTT - Buy in must be 2 percent or less of total bankroll, or at lower limits, not more than $1.
- You should never play in a game that is beyond your bankroll
  simply because the game seems to be soft that day. It's never soft
  enough to risk money that puts your bankroll in jeopardy.

Answer (score 1):

That's called "going south." It's a violation of etiquette at the higher levels of play, and probably won't be noticed at the lower levels.

If you're nervous having that big of a stack in front of you, cash out, take a 20 minute walk to clear your head, and then get back on the table with a regular buy in. The advantage of having a big stack at a table isn't an advantage if you're too nervous that your BR can't handle the swing.

Answer (score 1):

Before choosing what to do, you should ask yourself a few questions:

- What is the average stack?
- Did I loose 12 caves because I am unlucky or are the others better than me?
- Do I have some kind of edge on my opponents that can makes me win over them for the rest of this session?

If those 1000 can allow you to see more flops and put pressure, you should stay in. Otherwise, I don't see any reason, excepted believing in your luck, to stay at the table.

Good luck :)